# Most efficient method to load DataSet from subset of multiple joined tables

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a large inventory system, and I'm having to re-write part of the I/O portion of it.  At its heart, there's a product table and a set of related tables.  I need to be able to read pieces of it as efficiently as possible.  From C# I construct this query:

```
select *                                    -- includes productid
into #tt
from products where productClass = 547      -- possibly more conditions
select * from #tt;
select * from productHistory where productid in (select productid from #tt);
select * from productSuppliers where productid in (select productid from #tt);
select * from productSafetyInfo where productid in (select productid from #tt);
select * from productMiscInfo where productid in (select productid from #tt);
drop table #tt;
```

This query gives me exactly the results I need: 5 result sets each having zero, one or more records (if the first returns zero rows, the others do as well, of course).  The program then takes those result sets and crams them into an appropriate `DataSet`.  (Which then gets handed off into a constructor expecting just these records.)  This query (with differing conditions) gets run a *lot*.

My question is, is there a more efficient way to retrieve this data?

Re-working this as a single join won't work because each child might return a variable number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have it already, I would strongly suggest making this a stored procedure.

Also, I suspect, but can't prove without testing it, that you will get better performance if you perform joins on the products table for each of your subtables rather than copying into a local table.

Finally, unless you can combine the data, I don't think there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: I'll probably boil this into SP's once I settle on the best way to do it.  At least then the query plan is already compiled somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an index on products.productClass this might yield better performance.

```
    select * from products where productClass = 547   -- includes productid    
    select productHistory.* 
    from productHistory 
    join products 
      on products.productid = productHistory.productid 
      and products,productClass = 547;
    ...
```

If productID is a clustered index then you will probalbly get better permance with

```
    CREATE TABLE #Temp (productid INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED);
    insert into #temp
    select productid  from products where productClass = 547 
    order by productid;
    go
    select productHistory.* 
    from productHistory 
    join #Temp 
      on #Temp.productid = productHistory.productid;
```

A join on a clustered index seems to give the best performance.
Think about it - SQL can match the first and know it can forget about the rest then move to the second knowing it can move foward (not go back to the top).
With a where in (select  ..) SQL cannot take advantage of order.
The more tables you need to join the more reason to #temp as you take about 1/2 second hit creating on populating the #temp. 
If you are going to #temp you might as well make it a stuctured temp.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure when you `JOIN` tables you are joining on indexes. Otherwise you will end up with table scans vs index scans and your code will be very slow specially when joining large tables.

Best practice is to optimize your SQL Queries to avoid table scans.

Comment: you can comment on the specific query he posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your schema and knowing a little more about your data and table sizes, it's hard to suggest definitive improvements on the query side.

However, instead of "cramming the results into an appropriate DataSet," since you are using a batched command to return multiple result sets, you could use SqlDataAdapter to do that part for you:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet results = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(results);
```

After that, the first result set will be in results.Tables[0], the second in results.Tables[1], etc.